# Virtualization Solution for Family Use

Tags: virtual-desktop

I'm trying to put together a solution for my family (wife + three kids).  At the moment I have one newish desktop and a couple of aging laptops.  There are always arguments over who should have the fast desktop.  I'm thinking I would like to invest in a new powerful server and then run virtual desktops for each user off the server so that each user would have the same experience regardless of which actual PC they were using.  I would like to use just a Linux based desktop, but unfortunately I need to support some Windows games for the kids.  I've not tried wine for the games but would be willing to give it a try.

Any advice on what the setup should be would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, wine for games is not so appreciated if your kids want to play variaties of Windows games, only a few are well-supported. Refer to this [list](http://appdb.winehq.org/).

If you want to run games in a virtual machine, then your virtualization software has to support Hardware Acceleration. I had the best experience with [Vmware](http://www.vmware.com/)